# QPushbutton: Two different Font size

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to have two different Font size for the QPushButton?
For example, for the text "LIVE VIDEO' in a QPushButton, I want to have the font-size 16 for 'LIVE' and 12 for 'VIDEO'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derive from QPushButton and draw the text yourself. You can refer this post for reference.
[Two colours text in QPushButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852340/two-colours-text-in-qpushbutton)

Answer (score 0):

While what @abhilb suggests is possible I would go with a custom `QLabel` that is clickable, which is faster to implement.

Unlike `QPushButton` `QLabel` supports rich text formatting. If you set the text formatting to `Qt::RichText` you can put HTML inside meaning you can use `<font/>`, `<b/>` etc.

```
myLabel.setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
myLabel.setText("<font size='16'>LIVE</font><font size='12'/>VIDEO</font>");
```

I've added this formatting to a label in a widget of mine and you can see the results:

[image]

You just need to handle the `void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event);` or `void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event);` in order to make it properly clickable. The final touch would be to emit your own `clicked()` signal.

Comment: Yea but even with click handlers it still won't look or act anything like a button unless you go all the way and style it properly including hover/press and all that. And it still won't look like the rest of the application unless all the push buttons are styled the same way. Re-implementing paintEvent() seems much simpler IMHO.